# Google Sign-In: Access token validation?

Tags: python, google-signin

I'm working on a project where I need to perform Google Sign-In's. Udacity provided me this sample code for the servers backend:
[Google Sign-In example from Udacity](https://github.com/udacity/ud330/blob/master/Lesson2/step5/project.py)

They implemented the [Google Sign-In flow for server-side apps](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/server-side-flow) in the `gconnect()` function and I finally managed to understand (on a very high level) what is going on there.

But why are they doing this access token validation/verification!? (Line 64 to Line 90) I couldn't find any reasons in the official documentation. It also calls the tokeninfo endpoint (Line 66), which is only recommended for debugging and not for a production environment, right!?

Comment: token validation is necessary so that a bad app can't send you a fake token and take over your user's accounts...

Comment: @StevenSoneff what to you mean by "bad app"?